# How does Apache Server, PHP interpreter, PostgreSQL work together what are their role when used together

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

I am doing a project on android application developement i need to know hpw does 3 thish work together what are their task when working togeather in as simple language as possible I want it in words so that even a layman would catch it easily!

Comment: This question is not appropriate for StackOverflow. Try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as that

```
HTTP-client (browser) <--> HTTP server (apache) <--> PHP interpreter <--> Postgres
```

- Client sends request
- Apache resends it to PHP
- PHP queries PG, gets data, renders it as HTML (or JSON) and returns it to Apache
- while Apache sends the response to client
- Client renders nicely looking page